# while running the smart contract uisng polkadot api i get the following error

Tags: substrate-contracts-node, substrate-api-client

while running the smart contract uisng polkadot api i get the following error

```
file:///Users/.../Documents/Study%20related/Learning-JS/ipfs_ink/node_modules/@polkadot/api-contract/base/Contract.js:81
    gasLimit = BN_ZERO,
    ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'gasLimit')
    at ContractPromise.#read (file:///Users/.../Documents/Study%20related/Learning-JS/ipfs_ink/node_modules/@polkadot/api-contract/base/Contract.js:81:5)
    at file:///Users/.../Documents/Study%20related/Learning-JS/ipfs_ink/node_modules/@polkadot/api-contract/base/Contract.js:40:71
    at Object.addMaterialPassport (file:///Users/.../Documents/Study%20related/Learning-JS/ipfs_ink/node_modules/@polkadot/api-contract/base/Contract.js:14:57)
    at main (file:///Users/..../Documents/Study%20related/Learning-JS/ipfs_ink/index_1.js:409:78)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

i tried to give gasLimit in the program as 10000n * 1000000n and later i tried with -1;

but error remains the same.
How to solve it

Using the developer node of substrate. Made the contract in Ink and trying to access it using metadata.json

I try to access it using a javascript program with @polkadot/api and @polkadot/api-contract packages.

Comment: What versions of the node and api?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: node version is Node v0.20.0-8d76d04faca.   Api @polkadot/api is latest. That is 9.9.1

Comment: using the developer node of substrate. Made teh contract in Ink and trying to access it using metadata.json

Answer (score 1):

You can estimate gas consumption by doing a `query` first and then passing the value in your `tx`

Have a look at this [doc](https://docs.astar.network/docs/builder-guides/XVM%20and%20WASM/interact_with_wasm_contract#weight-estimation) about how to use polkadotjs for WASM smart-contracts